# Append template parameter with htaccess for joomla

Tags: regex, .htaccess, joomla, parameters

I have a joomla (1.6) site that generates static pages, so when I enter from mobile devices, the template won't recognize the user agent.
So the thing is to redirect to a parameter for selecting the mobile template..

for the homepage I have to redirect to index.php?template=mobile
and for articles must redirect to /cat/cat/article-SEF-direction/?template=mobile

in the homepage wont work just "/?template=mobile" must have the "index.php"

So trying to add by .htaccess I've added this and worked for the homepage redirection:

```
# MOBILE
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "Windows CE" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "Blackberry" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "NetFront" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "Palm OS" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "Blazer" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "Elaine" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "iPhone" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "iPod" [NC,OR]
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "iPad" [NC,OR]
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "Android" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "Plucker" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "AvantGo" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "Symbian OS" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "Nokia" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(nokia|BlackBerry).*$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^/?$ /index.php?template=mobile [NC]
```

Now the thing is to append the parameter to articles URL without having to declare all categories and sub-categories as folders

this might need a good regex =)
thanks in advice

Comment: What do you mean by: *"append the parameter to articles URL without having to declare all categories and sub-categories as folders"*? What articles URL? What categories do you declare (what are categories in this context)??

Comment: I mean declare all categories one by one like:
`
RewriteRule ^/category1/sub-cat11/([0-9]+)- /?template=mobile [QSA]
RewriteRule ^/category2/([0-9]+)- /?template=mobile [QSA]
RewriteRule ^/category3/subcat31/subcat311/([0-9]+)- /?template=mobile [QSA]
`
I don't want to do this because of the changing categories all the time. Thanks for your help

Comment: just change the `^/?$` to `^.*$`, then everything gets sent to index.php, unless you want your categories to be handled differently

Comment: I've thought it's the same redirecting to the index.php instead of the static page..
something like RewriteRule (.*) /$1 [L] just for mobile...

any suggestions?